# how to implement hill like below image in libgdx?

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I generate a chain shape like this dynamically

[image]

and my question is:
how to draw ground like below image dynamically?

thanks

[image]

Comment: maybe this gives you some idea, not if you mean to create a 3D model or image http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19361733/java-texture-png-modificaiton

Comment: @AngelAngel Thanks for answering,I maybe use mesh to do this, and should learn something about it.

Comment: I just reread your question, and I have a doubt, you want a model to follow that recocorrido is generated, or want to generate or cause a simulation of a soil on that image, box2d

Comment: I want to simulate a mountain for infinite level, For now I can generate infinite path and simulate physics and wanna convert path to like second image.

Comment: Pretty sure the method is fully explained on the page you got that image from :)