# Java: Saving Graphics to background BufferedImage

Tags: java, graphics, awt, bufferedimage

So right now my `paint()` repeatedly paints a BufferImage over and over again. Is there any way of adding new Graphics to this BufferedImage variable?

`img` is a variable that stores a .png file that we will draw over.

```
img = ImageIO.read(new File(fileName));
```

My `paint()` functions draws this .png image over and over again.

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);

    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY);
}
```

How would I add Graphics changes (i.e. lines) to the `img` variable?

Comment: Please clarify: Are you trying to draw lines over an image that remain or that are dynamically changing?

Comment: If so, an example of how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40439601/522444)

Comment: Having obtained a `BufferedImage` via `ImageIO.read()`, you can use `BufferedImage.getGraphics()` to get a `Graphics` by which to draw on it.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914265/drawing-multiple-lines-in-a-bufferedimage, for example.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yes, I am drawing lines over an image that is dynamically changing.

Comment: Then again as per my answer in my [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40439601/522444) in my second comment, get the BufferedImage's Graphics object and draw on it, but be sure to dispose of it when done.

Comment: Ok thank you guys for the help!